# Laravel - Contact data not showing from database

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.7

m trying to show contact data of site on admin panel but it says page not found. the main thing is to show contact data at admin panel

here is code of ContactController:

```
  public function viewContact(){
    $contact = Contact::get();
    return view('admin.contacts.view_contacts')->with(compact('contact'));
   }
```

code of view_contacts.blade.php:

```
  @foreach($contacts as $contact)
        <div class="control-group">
          <label class="control-label">{{ $contact->name }}</label>
          <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" class="span11" placeholder="First name" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
          <label class="control-label">{{ $contact->email }}</label>
          <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" class="span11" placeholder="First name" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
          <label class="control-label">{{ $contact->subject }}</label>
          <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" class="span11" placeholder="Company name" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
          <label class="control-label">Description</label>
          <div class="controls">
            <textarea class="span11" >{{ $contact->description }}</textarea>
          </div>
        </div>
        @endforeach
```

route:

```
  Route::get('/admin/contact','ContactController@Contact');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Your URL should be like this

```
localhost/laravel/spareparts/public/admin/contact
```

2) Your Route

```
Route::get('/admin/contact','ContactController@Contact');
```

3) Your method should be like this in ContactController

```
public function Contact(){
  $contacts = Contact::get();
  return view('admin.contacts.view_contacts')->with(compact('contacts'));
}
```

Comment: still says page not found

Comment: Please check updated answer else send screenshot of error you get so easily figure out error.

Comment: Ohh I got your problem. 1) You have defined the wrong route. Your url should be like this admin/contact at last instead of admin/view-contacts

Comment: Change your method name. See in my answer.

Comment: still same result

Comment: Check updated answer. Hope this will help. I assume you will proper flow of blade file after this.

Answer (score 0):

use this url: localhost/laravel/spareparts/public/admin/contact

Comment: Method App\Http\Controllers\ContactController::Contact does not exist.

Comment: modify method name : Contact()

Comment: nthing happen still same

Answer (score 0):

You made some mistakes here.

1. In your route  `Route::get('/admin/contact','ContactController@Contact');` you are addressing `Contact` method ,but in the controller you declared method named as `viewContact()` so you should change method name to `Contact()`.
2. Inside the Contact method you compacted `contact` variable , but in your blade you foreach looped as `@foreach($contacts as $contact)` .So you need to compact `contacts` in the method

   ```
   public function Contact(){
   $contacts = Contact::get();
   return view('admin.contacts.view_contacts')->with(compact('contacts'));
   }
   ```